# Matlab Image Segmentation and Circle Identification

Tags: image, matlab, image-segmentation

I am working on image segmentation, edge detection, and opening and closing by reconstruction in Matlab. I am trying to identify circular objects in a very noisy image with the aim of creating a mask with the edges of these circular objects and then superimposing such mask in the original image. After applying opening and closing by reconstruction along with the watershed function to identify objects' boundaries and a binary mask of the original image, I am able to get edges corresponding to full and half circles. Although the full circles identified are very few and I mostly get half circles, this method filters out most of the noise from the image.

Trying to get the edges of full circles, I used the canny function for edge detection. This function gets the complete edges of the majority of the circular objects, but it also draws the edges of the noise in the image. This doesn't allow me to create a good mask to superimpose in the original image.

The question then is if there is any efficient method to get rid of the noise picked up by the canny function or if it is possible to do canny function edge detection on objects of certain radius only as the circular objects that I want to identify have an specific radius. Attached is the original image what causes the noise in the image are the dark vertical bands or shadows and the bright beams of light on top of the circles. P.S. The matlab function "imfindcircles" for circle detection does not work on my image because of the broken circular edges or the background noise.

Original image of circular objects and dark vertical lines and bright spots as noise

[image]

Comment: You can do hough transform. The noisy part of the edged will be filtered.

Comment: Hello Mendi. The imfindcircles function that I mentioned is a hough transform function in matlab. And it does not recognize the circles unless the edges are completely drawn and the circles are filled with one tone. Maybe I could use another circle detection method that doesn't involve hough transform?

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-process the given image before applying Hough transform. The problem you are getting is because of uneven distribution of brightness across the image. You can apply some filtering techniques like homomorphic filtering before edge detection and Hough transform. Homomorphic filtering technique normalizes the brightness across an image and increases contrast. Once you apply canny edge detection on this image, you can use some edge linking algorithm to fill the gaps between detected edges to get better performance using Hough transform.

The process goes like this,

image --> homomorphic filtering --> canny edge detection --> edge linking --> Hough transform